# Add HTML.php to next.js

Tags: php, html, web, next.js, server

I have ran my NPM run build for my web application I tried to host it on Hostinger and I got a 403 forbidden error!!!

I then spoke to chat support and they told me to add a index.html or Index.php file to my code and it should work I Am not too familiar with this and I am looking for some help thank you

I have tried numerous videos such as a static html export but I keep receiving errors with my code

Comment: Have you checked if the hosting account actually supports the type of application you're attempting to deploy to it? It doesn't sound like you've built a PHP application.

Comment: Ive not, I wasnt sure if it did or not, ive uploaded React files and that worked fine but I am coming to the conclusion that I does not support Next.js projects I have tried uploading on vercel too and I am getting errors there too but I think vercel may be my only option

Comment: I would imagine the sales literature would explain what is supported, or if you're unsure you can ask their technical support directly. From your report of your previous conversation it seems they may not have properly understood what you were attempting.